# Worst-case scenario for ShellExecute(0,"open",arbitrary_string)

Tags: windows

I found an application that uses [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open hyperlinks. However, it doesn't check if the string is actually a hyperlink - it is passed directly to ShellExecute.

Aside from opening arbitrary URLs (incl. custom registered application protocols, which [can be used to exploit vulnerabilities in them](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2012128/researchers-steam-url-protocol-can-be-abused-to-exploit-game-vulnerabilities.html)), this allows opening any file on the filesystem given its absolute path. I don't think it's possible to launch programs with custom parameters directly.

Aside from relying on vulnerabilties in other apps' custom protocol handling, what's the worst-case scenario of such a vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of things you could do with this issue:

- Set up a shared directory on the network, put an executable on it, then send the path to that share.
- Open the user's browser to a page containing browser exploits, by passing the URL.
- Launch a game in order to generate a temporary DoS whilst it loads.
- Launch a maintenance script for a known-installed application in order to damage or destroy data.
- Launch a network service that's available on the system, then use that to gain further access.